# IIS7 File Upload Timeout Issues

Tags: iis-7, timeout, upload

I think I have two problems, though they might be related:

- Trying to upload a large file, it fails. Uploading small files works.
- After a while the session times out.

To eliminate the timeout I tried to configure that in web.config file. But it didn't seem to have any effect.

The site is hosted on IIS7.

**Update:**
I tried http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/ramon/archive/2009/03/13/how-to-enable-large-file-uploads-in-iis7.aspx

Changed the `web.config` as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="50384" executionTimeout="3600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1200"/>

<system.webServer>
     <security>
       <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="60000000"></requestLimits>
```

Still cannot upload 16 MB file: "the connection with server was reset"

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I don't understand the second question, the first has a few options...

First off, see [this blog entry](http://www.cyprich.com/2008/06/19/fixing-file-upload-size-limit-in-iis-7/).

Also if you're using classic ASP (rather than .NET) then you'll need to adjust the value against maxRequestEntityAllowed, which you can do through the command line with:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:asp /limits.maxRequestEntityAllowed:nnnn
```

replacing `nnnn` with however many bytes you want to allow.

Comment: I want to stop or increase session time , or make it infinity

Answer (score 0):

Regarding large uploading, look up UploadReadAheadSize.

EDIT: IIS has various timeouts that you can set. See, for example, this link:

https://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/limits

Comment: I want to stop or increase session time , or make it infinity